# What is a maven pom tag?

Tags: spring, maven-3

I was looking through a Spring example and they had this curious comment around a standard maven pom dependency:

```
<!-- tag::security[] -->
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<!-- end::security[] -->
```

That is that tag::security and end::security XML comment for? The way it is formatted it looks like something is going to process it, something other than Maven...

Comment: I can't see any security, there are just dependency, for security purpose (for application) you can add spring-security-starter if you wish

Comment: The tags is nothing to do with Spring Security, I have posted its purpose as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example was generated by [AsciiDoc](http://www.methods.co.nz/asciidoc/), you can also refer to [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/README.adoc) for more detailed information.

If you want to include some parts of `pom.xml`, you can use following syntax:

```
include::complete/pom.xml[tag=security]
```

The tag `<!-- tag::security[] -->` and `<!-- end::security[] -->` are markers which allow **AsciiDoc** to extract partial document and insert them into guides or examples.